# Bayesian probabilistic theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

Let's have a look at the question.

**There are two students, S1 and S2. They are collecting marbles. For every 100 marbles collected by each collectively, s1 collects 70 out of which 56 are green and 14 are blue marbles. Whereas, S2 collects 30 in which 27 are green and 3 blue marbles. After completion they mixed them up forming a pile of 100 marbles. After choosing two marbles randomly, one of them is found to be green. Now I'm trying to find out the probability of the second being blue. How can I achieve this using bayes theorem?**

I tried but couldn't be succeded. I thought P(S1) = 0.7; P(S2)  = 0.3; P(B|S1) = 0.8; P(G|S1) = 0.2; P(B|S2) = 0.9; P(G|S2) = 0.1. But couldn't go forward. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it your choice to use Bayes theorem or are you commanded to do so in the exercise?

Comment: The question is defined to be done using bayes theorem @drhab